# How may i get /var/log/dnf.log to log times in my system timezone?

Tags: logs, dnf, timezone

How may i get /var/log/dnf.log to log times in my system timezone?  Neither man dnf nor google have yet enlightened me on this.  Centos8/rhel8.

Comment: Are you saying that when you run `date`  it shows different time than what appears in `/var/log/dnf.log`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the source of confusion was the system in question was configured for UT rather than our timezone.  i remained unaware of that because my. bashrc sets TZ, thus hiding the system timezone.  So the answer to the question is dnf.log already does log times using the system timezone.